# Class is not able to find another class (Separate Header Files): C++

Tags: c++

This is my Pizaa.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PIZZA_H
#define PIZZA

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


/****************************
 Abstract Base Pizza Class
*****************************/

class Pizza{
string name;
string dough;
string sauce;
std::list<string> topping;

    public:
Pizza(string name,string dough,string sauce);
void prepare();
virtual void bake()=0;
virtual void cut()=0;
void box();
string getName();
void addTopping(string str);
void getTopping(std::list<string>& lst);
virtual ~Pizza();
};

#endif
```

This is cheesePizza.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CHEEZEPIZZA_H
#define CHEEZEPIZZA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Pizza.h"

using namespace std;

class cheesePizza:public Pizza{
public:
cheesePizza();
~cheesePizza();
virtual void bake();
virtual void cut();
    };

#endif
```

This is veggiePizza.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef VEGGIEPIZZA_H
#define VEGGIEPIZZA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Pizza.h"


class veggiePizza:public Pizza{
public:
veggiePizza();
~veggiePizza();
virtual void bake();
virtual void cut();
    };

#endif
```

And this is my Factory class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Pizza.h"
#include "cheesePizza.h"
#include "veggiePizza.h"

using namespace std;

class SimplePizzaFactory{
public:
enum PizzaType {
         cheesePizza,
         veggiePizza
         };
Pizza* createPizza(PizzaType type)
{
    switch(type){
        case cheesePizza:
                       // Pizza* p = new cheesePizza(); ##Here
                       //delete(p); ##Here
        case veggiePizza:;
                         // return new veggiePizza();
        }
        throw "Invalid Pizza Type";
    }
    };



int main()
{

    Pizza* p = new cheesePizza();
    delete(p);
    return 0;
    }
```

My `SimplePizzaFactory` method `createPizza()` is not able to find `new cheesePizza()` & `new veggiePizza()` and I get below error if I uncomment `#Here`

```
$ g++ -Wall -c SimplePizzaFactory.cpp -o SimplePizzaFactory.o
SimplePizzaFactory.cpp: In member function ‘Pizza* SimplePizzaFactory::createPizza(SimplePizzaFactory::PizzaType)’:
SimplePizzaFactory.cpp:19:33: error: expected type-specifier before ‘cheesePizza’
                  Pizza* p = new cheesePizza();
                                 ^
SimplePizzaFactory.cpp:21:8: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
   case veggiePizza:;
        ^
SimplePizzaFactory.cpp:19:25: error:   crosses initialization of ‘Pizza* p’
                  Pizza* p = new cheesePizza();
                         ^
SimplePizzaFactory.cpp:17:8: warning: enumeration value ‘veggiePizza’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
  switch(type){
```

All my files i.e `*.o` & `*.cpp` are placed in the same folder.

I am not able to figure out why this error. The same code 
`Pizza* p = new cheesePizza();
        delete(p);` inside `main()` works fine, but if you uncomment `#Here` it gives compilation error.

Comment: You have an enum `cheesePizza` and a class `cheesePizza`.

Comment: You are right `changing enum PizzaType {          cheese,          veggie          };` resolved the issue

Comment: I don't see how polymorphism applies to this, it should be just a normal class with properties to fill (and certainly not strings, I want to see you fill an Elephant Trunk and Cheese Pizza order).

Comment: @Blindy `Pizza` class has `Bake()` and `cut()`as `pure virtual functions` implemented by their derived classes `cheesePizza & veggiePizza` . Polymorphism acheived :) Anyways Just implementing `Head First: Design Patterns` book's patterns in C++; so the examples and methods referred from there

Comment: Polymorphism might be achieved, but it's still a wrong use of it. In point of fact, both pizza subclasses bake (put in oven for x minutes) and cut (cut in 8 slices or whatever) exactly the same.

Comment: @Blindy What are trying to point out? I did not get you. The next implementation of `Pizzastore` will use this factory class. Trying my hands at `Factory Pattern` and implementing the classic example mentioned in any design pattern book .. You confused me :(

Comment: @Blindy how can you say they are the same?? No implementation is provided. Perhaps one bakes in 5 minutes the other in 8, perhaps on bakes in a wood oven the other in an electric oven, who cares what the actual implementation is. The point is that they don't have the be the same, that's what its all about.

Comment: @GauravK by the way you shouldn't be `using namespace std` the only reason textbooks do this is to save space as they have to fit code on paper pages. Doing it in practice, doing it in real code is very bad form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring cheesePizza both as an element of an enumeration and as a class, probably the enumeration element gets precedence.

Rename one of the two to solve your problem.

The reason that it works in main is that there the cheesePizza enumeration element is out of scope, so there is no nameclash there.

If you would have reduced your program to a minimal example exhibiting the problem you would most likely have found the problem yourself.

Comment: You are right changing `enum PizzaType {
         cheese,
         veggie
         };` resolved the issue